# How to insert new item into linked list in C (at the end of the list)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to get my head around Linked Lists in C, and have ended up confusing myself.

**My question is: Is this correctly inserting the different `people` at the end of the list? Or is it simply inserting them at the beginning?**

At the moment I'm trying to insert a new `person` at the end of my linked list. My struct is defined as follows:

```
struct person {
     char *name;
     int age;
     struct person *next;
};
```

I'm accessing the data from pre allocated arrays:

```
#define HOW_MANY 7
char *names[HOW_MANY]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John","Tim","Harriet"};
int ages[HOW_MANY]= {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};
```

Here is my insert at the end function:

```
static struct person * insert_end(struct person *people, char *name, int age)
{
    struct person *newPeople = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    if (newPeople == NULL)
    {
        perror("Memory allocation failed");
        abort();
    }
    newPeople->name = name;
    newPeople->age = age;
    if (people == NULL)
    {
        newPeople->next = people;
        people = newPeople;
        return people;
    }
    else {
        while(newPeople->next != NULL)
        {
            newPeople->next = people;
        }
        people = newPeople;
        return people;
    }
}
```

I think that the while loop within the function is not being executed, and I can't figure out why. 
Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no code-review service. If you have a problem with your code, provide a **specific** problem description and post a [mcve]. Until then, a debugger will be your best friend.

Comment: And do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: If you are adding at the end, then `newPeople->next` will always be `NULL`. To add `newPeople` into the list, you will need to walk `people` until you reach `people->next == NULL` in which case this `people->next` should point to `newPeople`.

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed putting the new record at the beginning of the list. You must realize that newPeople->next will always be null as it is freshly allocated. You need to iterate through people until people->next is NULL and then asign newPeople.

Answer (score 0):

`newPeople->next` is not given a value before it is read leading to undefined behavior.  So code was not properly inserting at the end nor beginning.

```
while(newPeople->next != NULL)  // undefined behavior
```

The following does *not* initialize the objected pointed to by `newPeople`.

```
struct person *newPeople = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
```

---

Code appears to be making a circular linked-list with the following.

```
 if (people == NULL) {
    newPeople->next = people;
    ...
```

Although that is OK, it is more common to form a `NULL` terminated list and I'll assume that is your goal.

```
static struct person * insert_end(struct person *people, char *name, int age) {

    // struct person *newPeople = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    // No need for cast.  Recommend sizeof object rather than sizeof type
    struct person *newPeople = malloc(sizeof *newPeople);
    if (newPeople == NULL) {
        ...
    }

    // Best to initial all fields.
    newPeople->name = name;
    newPeople->age = age;
    newPeople->next = NULL; 

    if (people == NULL) {
        return newPeople;  // New head node
    }
    // else not needed
    // else {

    // Code was attempting to march down wrong list.  
    // Create `walker` instead.
    struct person *walker = people;
    while(walker->next != NULL) {
      walker = walker->next;
    }
    walker->next = newPeople;
    return people;
  }
```